# Angular2 url not update with browser navigation

Tags: url, angular, navigation

When I press back or forward button from my browser, the url doesn't changes, but the view is correctly updated.
My routing setup is the one by default when you create a new app with Angular-CLI.
What do I have to configure to tell Angular to update the URL when I press back and forward buttons?

Comment: angular 6 has fixed this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.10/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. It may be related to this open issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8707

Comment: It seems to be working on Angular 2.0.0. But it no longer works on Angular 2.1. Thank you for your reply. (Should I mark it as answer even if there is no real solution?)

Comment: @Ben can you provide the package.json that it does work with?